# Como puedo hacer que cambie la imagen al hacer Hover con el mouse?

Tags: html, css

Miren, intento que al pasar el mouse por la foto de la chinchilla de espaldas, cambiase a la foto de la chinchilla de frente, lo intenté hacer yo mismo con el código que he hecho yo pero el efecto resultante que veo es que parpadea de una manera muy extraña al pasar el mouse por encima. ¿Alguna solución para corregirlo? Soy novato en HTML/CSS y aunque miro vídeos me resulta confuso. Gracias por la ayuda.

Aqui los archivos:
https://github.com/MiguelGarciaRodriguez98/testingrepository1

Y aqui un ejemplo del problema: https://gyazo.com/07772c6e9c22e095a0f202aa7bfba9c8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ese problema de que la imagen parpadee es muy comun cuando se utiliza la posicion absoluta, puedes solucionarlo si intercambias la imagen de la chinchilla jugando con la opacidad, simplemente intercambia esto que tienes tu:

```
.item1 #chinchillaback:hover, .item1 #chinchillafront:hover{
position: absolute;
margin-right: 100px;
z-index: -10;
}
```

Por esto:

```
.item1 #chinchillaback:hover{
opacity: 0;
}
```

Espero que te haya ayudado :)